# How do you access a macro in the AOT macro node?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I have the following macro in the macro node of the AOT in AX 2012

```
#localmacro.printSettings
    classStr(SrsPrintDestinationSettings), xSession::systemSessionId()
#endmacro
```

How can I then access this in code?  Basically i want to be able to pass certain print settings to the macro and then grab those settings using the macro as well.

Comment: It is difficult from your question to infer what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros can only manage parameters that make sense to be writed on the source code. They are not intended to receive and manage objects as parameters. If you need so, you'll need to implement a regular method, as Jan B. Kjeldsen stated on their answer.

Answer (score 2):

The use of macros is all explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197107.aspx).

Do not make it too complicated, if it is, you are better served using regular methods.